# How to secure swagger documentation access

Tags: node.js, swagger

I've created a swagger documentation for my api, however I don't want to expose the documentation url for everyone, I want to protect this route : mydomain.com/api-docs only for users with specific token (eg: admin), I have a middleware to check user role before any actions of controllers, so my question is how to secure this route :

```
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));
```

I have already tried to use like this, without success :

```
app.use("/api-docs",my_Middleware, swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs));

// Middleware
...
const payload = jwt.decodeToken(token);
const user = User.findOne({ _id: payload.id });
const role = user.role;
if(role !== "admin") { ... // throws an error here }
req.user = user;
next()
....
```

Comment: can you show code for my_Middleware?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, the middleware is so long but i modify post to show you the important part

Comment: Is that correct to use User.findOne without async?

Comment: This code still can't show how you throw the error

Comment: Hi, there is no error thrown, i just able to access the doc event with the middleware

Comment: without or with asynbc